# Search suggestion html input

Tags: javascript, html, json, search

I actually working on a website-project. Behind my website, I´ve got a database with recipes.

Now to my problem: on the top of my page, I´ve got a textarea, with which it should be possible to search recipes in the database. 
My database gives back the following JSON-Object:

```
{"Data":{"Recipes":{"Recipe_7":{"ID":"7","TITLE":"Wurstel"},"Recipe_43":{"ID":"43","TITLE":"Wurstel2"}}},"Message":null,"Code":200}
```

I´ve already parsed it that I only have the title:

```
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)

    {
       var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);
    var str="";
    $.each(obj.Data.Recipes, function(){
    str += this.ID + "<br/>";
    str += this.TITLE + "<br/><br/>";
        });
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = str;
    document.getElementById("txtHint").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
```

What I don´t know now is, how to write the str string into a dropdown beneath the search-textarea. What type of element is this?

Comment: No, the dropdown should be shown while I search something. The function that I can search "live" is already written, I just don´t know how the element is called

Comment: See this, http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp , this gets the remote json data and appends to the suggestion.. I think this could help you.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, you can simply select the element by using a CSS selector (ie: $("#txtHint") ), and then call functions on that DOM element jQuery returned.

Comment: Try to avoid `.innerHTML`. It is evil.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a great example! On [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp) so there is all the code you would need to get this to work for your project!

I hope this helps you out :)

Comment: This is a solid solution. Regardless of which "website" its on. Your post isnt constructive to the OP.

Comment: I know the solution isn't bad or anything. I'm just letting you know that linking to W3Schools isn't good. It's just to spread awareness of how W3Schools doesn't update it's content and it could be misleading at times.

Comment: That example you linked is full of bad code and bad practices. Please don't like to w3schools.

Comment: hardly worth a down vote. it answers the posters question and provides him with a link to where to go and further his project. No where did i say "This is the absolute 100% code you NEED to use."

Answer (score 0):

try using https://github.com/httpcart/SuggestionsAndSearchJs
Everything works out in one line